# EJB Interceptor

Tags: java, ejb

Приветствую! Возникла сложная (для меня) ситуация с перехватчиком. Суть в следующем. Есть один пакет, где находится метод, параметры которого следует перехватить. А в другом пакете находится сам перехватчик. Дескриптор развертывания находится в пакете с классом интерцептором в фолдере META-INF.

Сам интерцептор ide находит (не горит красным цветом в xml, так как находится в том же пакете), но требуемый метод и класс найти не может, так как находится в другом пакете. (я так думаю из-за этого) 
На все восклицания идеи забил и попробовал перехватить прилетающие параметры в метод, предварительно сбилдившись, но не получилось. В таргете все классы есть, ejb-jar.xml в джарнике есть.

И да, изменять код класса, где находится метод, параметры которого нужно перехватить, изменять нельзя, т.е. все нужно через дескриптор делать.

Comment: Фолдер META-INF должен находится не в пакете, а в корне архива jar

Comment: @Sergey, в сбилженном состоянии он и находится в корне архива jar.

Comment: Так это Web-приложение? WAR? Оно разве заглядывает в META-INF, если написано, что для war ejb-jar.xml должен находится в WEB-INF и EJB-архивы не воспринимаются как EJB-архивы? `JAR files that contain enterprise bean classes packaged within a WAR module are not considered EJB JAR files, even if the bundled JAR file conforms to the format of an EJB JAR file.`

Comment: @Sergey, извиняюсь. Не в варнике есть, как я писал выше, в джарнике конечно же.

Comment: Тогда может в ejb-jar по-другому назвали свои ejb и получилось два набора ejb. Один класс, имена разные. В программе используются одни, а интерцепторы зареганы на другие, которые не используются.